# WP Supersized not showing in Custom Content

Tags: wordpress, plugins, supersized

my WP Supersized (for Wordpress) is doing what it needs to be doing, BUT it doesn't show on posts from custom content types. I have another plugin installed, called Custom Content Type Manager, with menu's like Portfolio and News. But these posts don't show the "WP Supersized source of images" box beneath the content area. I have also checked the positions in the settings, it's set to: "Everywhere", "On all pages", "Portfolio" and "News". But it still doesnt give me the option to select the source. Am I missing something? Or doesnt WP Supersized handle custom types?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a conflict with the meta-boxes.  Debugging conflicts between plugins can be very difficult.